# Read and Write the specific content

Tags: python, file

I am trying to read specific content of a file1.txt and write this specific content in another file file2.txt. The problem is I read entire part after Bar where I want to read only the line start with [x] and only with the Bar section.

Source Code

```
def read_write_file_content():
    data_file = open('file1.txt')
    block = ""
    found = False

    for line in data_file:
        if found:
            if line.strip() == "##### Foo":
                break
            else:
                block += line

        else:
            if line.strip() == "##### Bar:":
                    found = True
                    block = line
    print block




    data_file.close()

view_today()
```

**Input file**
file1.txt

```
##### Xyz
* [] Task 112
* [] Cl 221

##### Foo
* [] Task 1
* [x] Clone 2


##### Bar:
* [x] Email to A
* [] Email to B
* [x] Email to C
##### Bob
* [] Task 3
* [x] Clone Bob
```

**Outputfile**
file2.txt

```
##### Bar:
* [x] Email to A
* [x] Email to C
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciate ? Thanks :)

[Subsequent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967710/read-and-append-the-specific-content)

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: yes. [x] is in starting of the line. Some lines are [ ] which is not our consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to detect whether you are inside a "Bar" block. Then, while you are, print/accumulate those lines that start with `* [x]`. Here's one way to do it:

```
def get_selected_block_entries(lines, block_name,
                               block_prefix='#####', selected_entry_prefix='* [x]'):
    selected_lines = []

    block_marker = '{} {}'.format(block_prefix, block_name)
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith(block_prefix):
            in_block = line.startswith(block_marker)
            if in_block:
                selected_lines.append(line)
        else:
            if in_block and line.startswith(selected_entry_prefix):
                selected_lines.append(line)

    return selected_lines

with open('file1.txt') as infile, open('file2.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    selected = get_selected_block_entries(infile, 'Bar:')
    print selected    # a list of selected entries within a Bar: block
    outfile.writelines(selected)
```

Running the above code when `file1.txt` contains:

```
##### Foo
* [] Task 1
* [x] Clone 2


##### Bar:
* [x] Email to A
* [] Email to B
* [x] Email to C

##### Foo
* [] Task 1
* [x] Clone 2
```

prints:

```
['##### Bar:\n', '* [x] Email to A\n', '* [x] Email to C\n']
```

which is list returned from the `get_selected_block_entries()` function. Similarly `file2.txt` contains:

```
##### Bar:
* [x] Email to A
* [x] Email to C
```

This output shows that selected entries following a "Bar:" block are not collected.

Also note that selected entries will be collected from all matching blocks if there is more than one, e.g.

`get_selected_block_entries(infile, 'Foo')` will return the selected entries from the *two* Foo blocks:

```
['##### Foo\n', '* [x] Clone 2\n', '##### Foo\n', '* [x] Clone 2\n']
```

And, if you ever wanted to select *all* selected entries from all blocks you could do this:

```
get_selected_block_entries(infile, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Toggle `found` on and off by detecting sections. When `found` is `True` filter the lines with `'[x]' in line`.

```
found = False

for line in open('file1.txt'):
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue
    if line.startswith('#####'):
        if line == '##### Bar:':
            found = True
            print(line)
        else:
            if found:
                break
        continue

    if found and '[x]' in line:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to test if a given line starts with `"* [x]"`.

```
import re
section = None
for line in data_file:
    sre = re.match("^#####\s*(\w):\s*",line)
    if sre:
        section = sre.group(1)
    if line.startswith("* [x]") and section == "Bar":
            block += line
```

Look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more information on using regular expressions in python.

Comment: thanks. However I can not still get expected output. The problem is I get all the lines after Bar  block start with * [x] where I want within Bar block