# Read and Append the specific content

Tags: python, file, append

Subsequent to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960264/read-and-write-the-specific-content) what if I want to append line. In that case others block are also specified in output file.

**Input file file1.txt**

```
##### Xyz
* [] Task 112
* [] Cl 221

##### Foo
* [] Task 1
* [x] Clone 2

##### Bar:
* [x] Email to A
* [] Email to B
* [x] Email to C

##### Bob
* [] Task 3
* [x] Clone Bob
```

**Outputfile file2.txt**

```
##### Xyz


##### Foo
* [x] Clone 2

##### Bar:
* [x] Email to A
* [x] Email to C

##### Bob
* [x] Clone Bob
```

The output file is predefined structure as shown in output file - file2.txt with specified blocks. If some new items content  * [x] are added in input file it shall append in output file, shall not add any duplicate items. It would be interesting to see the usage of argparse and append one specific block or entire block start with [x]. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Read all lines from the input file but write only those that start with specified strings:

```
with open("file1.txt", "rt") as finp:
    with open("file2.txt", "wt") as fout:
        for line in finp.readlines():
            if line.startswith("#####") or line.startswith("* [x]"):
                fout.write(line)
```

Comment: @user3100115 You are right, of course. I only wanted to avoid long first line. ;-) Well, seriously, I wanted to keep the code very explicit so I dedicated each line exclusively to one operation.

Comment: Question updated. Previous requirement clarification misleading the requirement.

Comment: It seems we are *not* creating the *output file* from the *input file*. Instead, we have to *update* one file according to the information present in the other file. Can you confirm that?

Comment: We are creating the output file. The main issue is the output file have same block structure as input file which are need to be added accordingly  and later on if there is any new item it shall append to existing block of the output file.

Comment: So you confirm that the *output* file exists before we run the program, and this output file has to be *updated* according to the information present in the *input* file. In other words, the resulting *output* file is actually a merge of the *input* file and the *original output* file.